# Can't get past CORS error on secured Google Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function. I created credentials for my project and authorized http://localhost & http://localhost:3000 as origins. I also have a Google user account that I gave the cloudfunctions.functions.invoke role to.  I confirm this by going to the cloud function in the console and expand the "Cloud Functions Invoker" item and see my account listed there.

I can successfully access the function with curl.

*curl https://[google-cloud-server]/test5 -H "Authorization: bearer my-identity-token"*

However, if I try to invoke the function from my React app (I tried both axios and fetch), I get the following error....

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://[google-cloud-server]/test5?a=b' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

A couple things to note...

1. There are no CORS problems if I make the function accessible to allUsers
2. Through logging, I have confirmed that, when secured, the request never makes it to the function where I have my CORS code for checking pre-flight OPTIONS.  This makes sense as it is supposed to be secured by Google. But all documentation I find on Google Cloud functions talking about handling CORS-related stuff from within the function. Something is responding to my React app's request before it reaches my function. I have no idea what/where.

I added so many tags to this post because I really don't know which layer is causing the problem. I'm probably doing something really obvious/stupid, but I'm out of ideas!

Cloud function....

```
exports.test5 = (req, res) => {

  console.log('function invoked');
  // Set CORS headers for preflight requests
  // Allows GETs from any origin with the Content-Type header
  // and caches preflight response for 3600s

  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    console.log('Determined it is OPTIONS request');
    // Send response to OPTIONS requests
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
    res.status(204).send('');
  } else {

    console.log('Main function body');
    res.send('Hello World!');
  }
};
```

Call from React client...

```
  const config = 
  {
    params: payload,
    headers: 
    { 
      Authorization: `bearer ${window.IDENTITY_TOKEN}`
    }
  };

  axios.get(url, config)
      .then((res) => {
          ...

      })
      .catch((err) => {
          handleError(err);
      });
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CORS preflight OPTION request does not have an Authorization header and Cloud functions IAM prevalidates the Authorization header and will not call the function if it is missing.Therefore in order to serve the CORS preflight response you have to allow allUsers access to your cloud function.

## Edit

They updated the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)

> If you want to build a web app that is secured with Google Sign-in and
> Cloud Functions IAM, you'll likely have to deal with Cross-Origin
> Resource Sharing (CORS). CORS preflight requests are sent without an
> Authorization header, so they will be rejected on all non-public HTTP
> Functions. Because the preflight requests fail, the main request will
> also fail.
>
> To work around this, you can host your web app and function(s) on the
> same domain to avoid CORS preflight requests. Otherwise, you should
> make your functions public and handle CORS and authentication in the
> function code.
>
> Alternatively, you can deploy a Cloud Endpoints proxy and enable CORS.
> If you want authentication capabilities, you can also enable Google ID
> token validation, which will validate these same authentication
> tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm probably not understanding you though as giving "allUsers" permission would give everyone permission to execute it  (I am talking about invoker role).
But anyway... your answer prompted me to go back and take another look at the doc and found where they suggest that you put both the web app and the cloud functions in firebase so they can be hosted at the same domain, thereby circumventing CORS issues. Seems like the right path, although I still couldn't make it all work today. However, I'll come back to it and post the resolution here when I get it all working.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you have to give everyone permission to execute if you want to be able to use preflight OPTIONS